# How can I use MS SQL Server's Integrated Authentication in IntelliJ IDEA 12?

Tags: sql-server, intellij-idea, mssql-jdbc

I have several database connections configured in IntelliJ IDEA. I'm connecting to MS SQL Server 2000/2005. The connections use Integrated Authentication, with the SQLJDBC4 driver.
I have the sqljdbc_auth.dll file in the same directory as the sqljdbc4 driver.

My configuration worked in IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.4 I just recently upgraded to 12.1.2 and now my connections throw an error about not being properly configured for Integrated authentication and that the driver cannot find the sqljdbc_auth.dll file.

So how can I add the sqljdbc_auth.dll file as one of the files to be loaded for my jdbc connections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have 64 bit Windows 7.

Solution steps

1. Switch to using the 64bit IntelliJ IDEA executable.
2. Figure out which installed 64bit JDK IDEA is loading on startup
    (the version is given in Help->About)
3. copy the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` file to the JDKs jre\bin\ folder

---

**File Locations on my machine:** (NOTE: I'm not sure which location is truly correct.)

1. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\`  <-- Current version of Java IntelliJ IDEA is using.
2. `C:\Windows\System32`

Comment: @naXa, I'm successfully using this with IntelliJ IDEA 13.1

Comment: For me, the folder I added the dll to was C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\jre\jre\bin

Comment: Worked in Rubymine 2017.2.3